# How to access and manipulate a flat file?

Tags: ruby, file, nomethoderror, nameerror, flat

In this Ruby exercise, I have to access a flat file with three songs containing the song's title, artist, length in minutes and seconds, and the file name. The exercise asks to do the following:

- break the line into fields,
- convert the running time from mm:ss to seconds, and
- remove those extra spaces from the artist's name.

I went ahead and copied and pasted the following into a plain text file and saved it as "songFile":

```
/jazz/j00132.mp3  | 3:45 | Fats     Waller     | Ain't Misbehavin'
/jazz/j00319.mp3  | 2:58 | Louis    Armstrong  | Wonderful World
/bgrass/bg0732.mp3| 4:09 | Strength in Numbers | Texas Red
         :                  :           :                   :
```

To break the songs lines into fields I put this in the terminal:

```
songs = SongList.new

songFile.each do |line|
  file, length, name, title = line.chomp.split(/\s*\|\s*/)
  songs.append Song.new(title, name, length)
end
puts songs[1]
```

and then got these two error messages:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `songFile' for main:Object
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Rails isn't magic, you can't just name a variable the same as your file and have Rails know that you intend to read a file. Look into `File.open`

Answer (score 0):

Open the file and do the things. Something like this

```
...
File.open("songFile") do |sf|
  sf.each do |line|
  ...
  end
end
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have **the text file in the same directory as the script** then

```
songs = SongList.new

File.readlines('./songFile').each do |song|
  file, length, name, title = line.chomp.split(/\s*\|\s*/)
  songs.append Song.new(title, name, length)
end

puts songs[1]
```